# Notification not firing when expected

Tags: android, angular, cordova, notifications, ionic4

I am using the recommended cordova plugin as used on the ionic website to implement notifications in my app, cordova-plugin-local-notifications.

When I schedule a notification using this format

```
  {
      title: 'Appointment!',
      text: 'You have an appointment at ' + e.startTime.toTimeString(),
      data: {
        eventid: e.id,
        event: e
      },
      trigger: { at: new Date(e.startTime) },
      foreground: true, // Show the notification while app is open
      priority: 1
    }
```

The notification on fires when I tell it to use the current time or a past time. If I set it for one minute in the future, the notification never appears.

Using android studio to debug I can see it set the event

```
2019-09-09 16:10:05.480 10287-10287/weusthem.myexp D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(javascript:cordova.plugins.notification.local.core.fireEvent("add",{"title":"Appointment!","text":"You have an appointment at 16:11:00 GMT-0300 (Atlantic Daylight Time)","data":"{\"eventid\":\"1568056205360Bob\",\"event\":{\"id\":\"1568056205360Bob\",\"title\":\"Bob\",\"startTime\":\"2019-09-09T19:11:00.409Z\",\"endTime\":\"2019-09-09T19:11:33.409Z\",\"allDay\":false,\"desc\":\"\",\"dateCreated\":\"2019-09-09T19:10:05.360Z\",\"provider\":{\"id\":\"Bob1567779696555\",\"name\":\"Bob\",\"jobTitle\":\"\",\"sees\":\"Both\",\"heardAboutFrom\":\"My Family Doctor\"}}}","trigger":{"at":1568056260409,"type":"calendar"},"foreground":true,"priority":1,"actions":[],"attachments":[],"autoClear":true,"defaults":0,"groupSummary":false,"id":0,"launch":true,"led":{"color":"#FFFFFF","on":500,"off":500},"lockscreen":true,"number":0,"progressBar":{"enabled":false,"value":0,"maxValue":100,"indeterminate":false},"showWhen":true,"silent":false,"smallIcon":"res:\/\/icon","sound":true,"vibrate":true,"wakeup":true,"meta":{"plugin":"cordova-plugin-local-notification","version":"0.9-beta.2"}},{"event":"add","foreground":true,"queued":false,"notification":0}))
```

and I can see the alarm fire when it's supposed to

```
2019-09-09 16:11:00.410 1365-2300/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 1 when =1568056260409 package =weusthem.myexp operation =*alarm*:NOTIFICATION_ID0-2 flags =0x1
```

But no notifications appear on the phone.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to assign an id to each notification, it won't assign them automatically. If you don't specify an id the notification will be overwritten by the next notification without an id. Very annoying as auto assigning ids would be very useful. My notifications were being overwritten by new notifications.